# Why does a new KDF/GAC filter cause a rotten egg smell/taste?

Tags: water-filtration

I installed a KDF GAC(4:6 by weight) filter (counter-top) to reduce possible heavy metals and chlorine in the water. (our water tastes generally good, except slightly chlorine)

However, after running the water through the filter we get a very strong rotten egg smell/taste. (assuming H2S)

*Note: The water states/smells fine before filtration (or on any other tap in the house) except for slightly chlorine.*

After some research; The filter should remove H2S not introduce it.

I can't find any reason other than it might be due to bacteria growth or the filter is saturated.
But since this is a new filter I got yesterday... I'm completely stumped.

**Why would a new KDF/GAC filter cause a rotten egg smell/taste?**

PS. I've also let it run for 5 minutes at +-5.56L/min (+- 28L) without any improvement.

Comment: Did you test the water for heavy metal? What is your water source?  Why did you choose to install this filter?  If chlorine is your only complaint install a simple charcoal filter instead.  If your looking for the purest drinking water install reverse osmosis.  The only reason you need that extremely high maintenance KDF/GAC filter is if you have contaminated well water, which is doubtful since you didn't install whole house KDF/GAG.

Comment: @Tyson KDF/GAG you replace less frequent than with a charcoal filter as you suggested. I'm not looking for an alternative. I want to know why it's happening and if something can be done about it. This is exactly the filter I want. I'll be installing a pure KDF whole house, once this problem has been clarified/solved. I don't need a RO system.

Comment: Why has it been closed? What details is lacking?

Answer (score 0):

We were told the smell was due to (harmless) bacteria specific to soft water.

Comment: If the smell is present even before installing a filter, then it's not relevant.